# How to make a private Sharepoint List public?

Tags: sharepoint-online

How can i make a private sharepoint list public. I have allready tried the trick with the Developer Tool. But no lock. Is there a way?

Gr. Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean about private list? If the list is only accessible to you, you can change the list permission settings. It is possible the list has its unique permission which blocks other users from accessing. You can check this [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782) for more information. It will help you understand the permission settings in SharePoint. Delete the unique permission shall make other users with permission in this site accessing the list.

Or you can simply [share it to other users](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/share-a-list-or-list-item-c270ccaf-89a2-4f7e-874a-5da98824d449).

Useful blog here:https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-list-unique-permissions-for-files-and-folders-on-a-sharepoint-site/

And if this does not help you, please provide more information about your private list, screenshot will be helpful.